# Get the position of an element with specific attribute value

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to get with xPath the position only of the first `element` which has the `attribute` value `true`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<elements>
    <element attribute="false"/>
    <element attribute="true"/>
    <element attribute="true"/>
</elements>
```

What I have so fare is:

```
 head(/elements/element[@attribute='true']/position())
```

Result:

```
 1
```

But it should be:

```
 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position()` returns the position of the element in the nodelist created by the predicate, i.e. with the `false` excluded. Instead of position, you can e.g. count the number of preceding elemements.

For example, this works even in XPath 1.0:

```
1+count(/elements/element[@attribute="true"][1]/preceding-sibling::element)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's (with XPath 3):

```
 head(index-of(/elements/element/@attribute, 'true'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
saxon-lint --xpath 'count(//element[@attribute="true"]/position())' file.xml
```

From Michael answer:

```
saxon-lint --xpath 'head(index-of(/elements/element/@attribute, "true"))' file.xml
```

### Output

```
2
```